# Clicking outside hides dropdown div

Tags: javascript, html

I can't figure out how to close this dropdown div when clicking outside of it. I've found versions that close when clicking outside as well as clicking on the dropdown but because my dropdown has multiple checkboxes I want to continue to allow clicking on the dropdown menu without the dropdown closing:

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.dropbtn:hover {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  min-width: 230px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  z-index: 1;
}
label {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 16px;
}
.show {
display:block; 
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="Vanilla">Vanilla</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="Chocolate">Chocolate</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="Strawberry">Strawberry</label>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could listen for a click on the document and just hide the dropdown. Downside is that click on the button toggles it then the click propagates and hides your dropdown. You can fix that by prevent propagation. You also need to do that for the click on the checkboxes.

```js
function myFunction() {
  event.stopPropagation();
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

document.onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.remove("show");
}
document.getElementById("myDropdown").onclick = function() {
  event.stopPropagation();
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  min-width: 230px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  z-index: 1;
}

label {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 16px;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="Vanilla">Vanilla</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="Chocolate">Chocolate</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="Strawberry">Strawberry</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. Just before seeing your answer I had already made it work but with a not so elegant method. Adding an onclick to the body tag (to remove("show")) and another to the dropdown (to add("show")) and adding stopPropagation to the button and dropdown.

Comment: You're welcome. Another way would be to detect where the click came from (eg using event.target) and use some logic to decide what to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution that will provide you direction:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button onclick="myFunction(event)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
    <div id="myDropdown"
         onclick="event.stopPropagation()"
         class="dropdown-content">
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="Vanilla">Vanilla</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="Chocolate">Chocolate</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="Strawberry">Strawberry</label>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
    .dropbtn {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: white;
        padding: 16px;
        font-size: 16px;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .dropbtn:hover {
        background-color: #3e8e41;
    }
    .dropdown {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #fff;
        min-width: 230px;
        overflow: auto;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    label {
        display: block;
        padding: 12px 16px;
    }
    .show {
        display:block;
    }
</style>

<script>
    function myFunction(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
    }

    document.addEventListener('click', () => {
        document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.remove("show");
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Oddly, it doesn't for me. I'm on Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Heres a readable solution i'll explain what's going on.

we want to be able to click anywhere but the dropdown to close so we add a click handler to the body to toggle the button on the body.

after we close we remove the listener.

`event.stopPropagation();` stops the body click from closing you dropdown when clicking on the drop down

```js
const dd = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
document.addEventListener('click', () => toggle("remove"));
dd.onclick = event => event.stopPropagation();

function toggle(key = "toggle") {
  event.stopPropagation();
  dd.classList[key]("show");
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  min-width: 230px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  z-index: 1;
}

body {
  height: 100vh
}

label {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 16px;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="toggle()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="Vanilla">Vanilla</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="Chocolate">Chocolate</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="Strawberry">Strawberry</label>
  </div>
</div>
```